# Passing controls across modules by System Filesystem

Tags: java, netbeans, module, netbeans-platform

I've a Netbeans Platform project with multiple modules which I'm trying to keep loosely coupled. I need the Top Component of one module to display buttons defined by other modules - these buttons will generally each open the top component of the module that defines it.

I've thought about passing the Swing controls through the Lookups, but after some reading I think now the best way to do this is using the "System Filesystem"

I think the module that will display the buttons should define a folder and modules that want buttons to be displayed should put these in that folder. I think that there really only needs to be three variables passed for each button - the button text, the action (I think Top Component opening actions get automatically made by NetBeans), and also a boolean that defines whether the button should be always enabled or only enabled when the displaying top component is in a certain state.

The thing is, I don't know how to set this up. How do I set it up? Ideally these buttons should appear when the corresponding modules are loaded, even if that module was not loaded initially, so the displaying module needs to be listening to the System Filesystem.

Comment: The reason I currently think what I do is largely because of reading a [page about the System Filesystem](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqSystemFilesystem) on the Netbeans wiki

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done it, though there's probably a better solution out there:

### 1. Passing control data through the filesystem

1. Add an xml layer file to the module that will display the controls (look under `Module Development` of the new file wizard.) and make it look like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE filesystem PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Filesystem 1.2//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/filesystem-1_2.dtd">
   <filesystem>
       <folder name="UI">
           <folder name="MyAppTools">
           </folder>
       </folder>
   </filesystem>
   ```

   This will define a folder in the system filesytem into which other modules may put their control data.
2. In the module that wants to add a control make an xml layer file that looks a bit like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE filesystem PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Filesystem 1.2//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/filesystem-1_2.dtd">
   <filesystem>
       <folder name="UI">
           <folder name="MyAppTools">
               <file name="module-package-path-buttonName">
                   <attr name="text" stringvalue="Button Text" />
                   <attr name="actionName" stringvalue="package.path.Class.handlerMethod" />
                   <attr name="alwaysEnabled" boolvalue="true" />
               </file>
           </folder>
       </folder>
   </filesystem>
   ```

   Put one file in the folder for each control that is to be created. You must make sure that the package that the XML files are in [is public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772317/make-a-modules-xml-layer-visible-to-other-modules) or these files wont affect the filesystem at runtime. (It took me ages to work this out)
3. Put these fields in the component to display the tools:

   ```
   public static final String TOOLS_PATH = "UI/MyAppTools";
   public static final String ATTR_NAME_BUTTON_NAME = "text";
   public static final String ATTR_NAME_BUTTON_ACTION = "action";
   public static final String ATTR_NAME_BUTTON_ACTION_NAME = "actionName";
   public static final String ATTR_NAME_BUTTON_BOOL_PROPERTY = "alwaysEnabled";
   private FileObject systemFsTools;
   ```

   Properly, the public constants should go in a public package that any module can depend upon, so that the modules providing tool data can make their XML files dynamically by reading these values. But I'm not doing it properly.
4. In the constructor of the displaying component add a FileChangeListener that will trigger when anyone puts a file into our special folder (or removes one):

   ```
   systemFsTools = FileUtil.getConfigFile(TOOLS_PATH);
   systemFsTools.addFileChangeListener(new FileChangeAdapter() {
       @Override
       public void fileDataCreated(FileEvent fe) {initControlPanel();}
       @Override
       public void fileDeleted(FileEvent fe) {initControlPanel();}
   });
   ```
5. Add this method to the displaying component so that when the content of our special folder is changed the panel showing the buttons is repopulated:

   ```
   private void initControlPanel()
   {
       // start fresh each time we build this
       panelTools.removeAll();
       selectionDependantTools.clear();
       // go to the folder where we can find the info for the buttons we're making
       DataFolder toolsFolder = DataFolder.findFolder(systemFsTools);
       DataObject[] children = toolsFolder.getChildren();
       // we're assuming each child in the folder represents one button
       for (DataObject child : children) {
           FileObject file = child.getPrimaryFile();
           // get the attributes that tell us what the button will be like
           Object actionMethodName = file.getAttribute(ATTR_NAME_BUTTON_ACTION_NAME);
           Object btnText = file.getAttribute(ATTR_NAME_BUTTON_NAME);
           Object btnAlwaysActive = file.getAttribute(ATTR_NAME_BUTTON_BOOL_PROPERTY);
           JButton btn = new JButton();
           if (btnText != null) {
               btn.setText((String)btnText);
           }
           if (actionMethodName != null) {
               final String identifier = (String)actionMethodName;
               btn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
                   {
                       @Override
                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                       {
                           // Whoever designated this button should handle its event
                       }
                   });
           } else {
               btn.setEnabled(false);
           }
           if (btnAlwaysActive != null) {
               if (((Boolean)btnAlwaysActive).booleanValue())
               {
                   // something to handle button state
               }
           }
           panelTools.add(btn);
       }
       panelTools.revalidate();
   }
   ```

   By the way, I have panelTools as a JPanel with a FlowLayout.

The one thing that is missing from this is how to get the module that designated the button to handle its event. Try as you might you can't make code in module A call a method in module B without A depending on B, so the displaying component can't simply call the handler in the other module even if told the handler's signature exactly. So...

### 2. Passing the event back to the module with the handler

To do this I made an "event bus" using the Lookup system

1. Put a [Central Lookup](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/central_lookup) in a public package that all modules can depend on.
2. In that same package make an interface:

   ```
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

   /**
    * This class defines something that modules can pass to each other through lookups
    * to "poke" each other when certain events happen
    * @author toby
    */
   public interface InterModuleEvent
   {    
       public ActionEvent getEvent();

       public String getIdentifier();

       public boolean hasIdentifier(String id);
   }
   ```

   so that modules will be able to deal with objects that come through the event bus with this interface. The identifier is so that the receiving (listening) modules can tell which events belong to them (it'll be the same string that they put as an identifier in the filesystem to make the button)
3. I implemented the interface with a class in the displaying module:

   ```
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import org.sil.jflavourapi.InterModuleEvent;

   public class ToolEvent implements InterModuleEvent
   {
       private ActionEvent event;
       private String identifier;

       public ToolEvent(ActionEvent event, String identifier)
       {
           this.event = event;
           this.identifier = identifier;
       }

       @Override
       public ActionEvent getEvent()
       {
           return event;
       }

       @Override
       public String getIdentifier()
       {
           return identifier;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean hasIdentifier(String id)
       {
           return identifier.equals(id);
       }

   }
   ```
4. Then all I needed to do was, whenever an event came up from one of these buttons I put one of these objects into the central lookup with the identifier that came from the button data in the filesystem. So in the `initConrolPanel` method where the comment is `// Whoever designated this button should handle its event` put this code:

   ```
   CentralLookup.getDefault().add(new ToolEvent(e, identifier));
   ```
5. So far so good. Next is for the module which designated the button to listen to the event bus for objects with the right identifier. The trick is that this module needs to be listening before the TopComponent is opened, so we need the listener to be set up as soon as the module is loaded. To do this we need to make an "installer" class in the module that is listening to the event bus (again look under `Module Development` of the new file wizard).
6. I tried making the Install be a listener for the event bus, but that didn't work, so instead I made another class to do this. I decided to make this a private subclass of the TopComponent class of the module that's listening to the event bus:

   ```
   private static class InterModuleEventHandler implements LookupListener
   {

       private Lookup.Result<InterModuleEvent> result = null;
       public final String MODULE_ID = "org.sil.jflavouritemeditor.JFlavourItemEditorTopComponent";
       public final String NEW_ITEM_ACTION_ID = "editNewItem";

       public InterModuleEventHandler()
       {
           result = CentralLookup.getDefault().lookupResult(InterModuleEvent.class);
       }

       public void startListening()
       {
           result.addLookupListener (this);
       }

       public void stopListening()
       {
           result.removeLookupListener (this);
       }

       @Override
       public void resultChanged(LookupEvent le)
       {
           Collection<? extends InterModuleEvent> allEvents = result.allInstances();
           if (!allEvents.isEmpty()) {
               InterModuleEvent event = allEvents.iterator().next();
               if (event.hasIdentifier(MODULE_ID + '.' + NEW_ITEM_ACTION_ID))
               {
                   MyClientTopComponent.myEventHandler();
                   CentralLookup.getDefault().remove(event);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   It's static so that it can be used without the host class (the TopComponent) having to instantiate. It listens to the central lookup and when an event matches it calls the handler in the host class and removes the event from the bus.
7. Put this code in the host class. All of it is static so we don't need to instantiate the TopComponent until necessary.

   ```
   private static InterModuleEventHandler imeHandler = new InterModuleEventHandler();

   public static void startHandlingInterModuleEvents()
   {
       imeHandler.startListening();
   }

   public static void stopHandlingInterModuleEvents()
   {
       imeHandler.stopListening();
   }

   public static void myEventHandler()
   {
       // This is where the button event handling actually happens
   }
   ```
8. Finally, in the "installer" class put this in the `restored()` method

   ```
   MyClientTopComponent.startHandlingInterModuleEvents();
   ```

This is quite convoluted and uses all three [registration methods listed in the wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqWhenToUseWhatRegistrationMethod). Perhaps someone else knows a simpler way to do it.

I'm surprised that this sort of thing isn't a common use case, at least not common enough for the Netbeans wiki to address, or for SO users to be able to offer any hints on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer works, but I think now I've found a simpler and better way to do it, using existing structures disgned to handle this sort of thing, namely the `NodeAction` class.

I would use the `Action` interface, which is more generic, except that in my case the actions are generally acting on nodes in the displaying Top Component and can be enabled or disabled depending on whether nodes are selected or not. So `NodeAction` helps me further by having this functionality built in.

The idea here is simply that the modules put their Actions into a specific lookup, which is where the displaying component will be listening, making the controls from the Actions it finds there. I haven't implemented it yet, but will try to soon.

1. Put a central lookup in a public package that all modules can depend on (as in section 2 in my first answer)
2. Modules that want to have controls displayed should make a class extending `NodeAction` and override `performAction(Node[])` for the action to do on selected nodes. Also override other methods for more specification such as `getName()`
3. These modules should each make an installer class with a `restored()` method that puts an instance of the `NodeAction` into the central lookup.
4. The displaying top component keeps a lookup result from the central lookup for `NodeAction`s and adds itself as a `lookupListener` for this.
5. In the `resultChanged(LookupEvent)` method the controls are reinitialised using the NodeActions found in the lookup

This solution has the advantage that the NodeActions used here can be used in other places (such as a context menu on the nodes themselves, or application menu) without extra worry. Also the enabling and disabling of the actions (and therefore any controls linked to them) is handled inside the Action object and would be set up by the module that creates the action. Also that module can also assign an icon to the action. Use of the System Filesystem becomes unnecessary.