# make a module's xml layer visible to other modules

Tags: java, netbeans, module, encapsulation, netbeans-platform

In Netbeans Platform I'm having one module watch the xml filesystem and respond when it's changed by other modules.

I've created a layer.xml in another module. The changes show up in the IDE when in the watching module I click on XML layer node and open up . However during runtime when the watching module is looking at the xml filesystem the changes from the other module aren't there. The other module *can* see its own changes during runtime.

Is there a setting somewhere for a module that lets other modules see its xml layer?

This is the code I'm using to inspect the xml filesystem during runtime - it prints the names of all nodes into a file, and I trigger it from a button when all modules are open and running.

```
private void btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                      
{                                       
    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("filesystemOut.txt"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        exportFilesystem(FileUtil.getConfigRoot(), writer, 0);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("couldn't write filesystem structure");
    }
}

void exportFilesystem(FileObject root, BufferedWriter writer, int depth) throws IOException
{
    for (int i = 0; i < depth * 4; ++i)
    {
        writer.write(' ');
    }
    writer.write(root.getName());
    writer.newLine();
    FileObject[] children = root.getChildren();
    for (FileObject child : children)
    {
        exportFilesystem(child, writer, depth + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the properties dialog of the module with the xml layer that needs to be visible. Select `API Versioning` and under `Public packages` select the package that contains the xml file. Click `OK`.